# How to import argparse when I am using qsub in Linux server?

Tags: python, linux, server, qsub

I want to use CoNIFER, which is a python program for bioinformatics.

So, I wrote a script for qsub because of my institute's rule.

Here is my qsub script. I inserted enter in front of -- to show it clear.

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N oh
#$ -cwd
cd /usr/etc/GRAPE_ENV/Python/
python /home/osj118/tools/conifer_v0.2.2/conifer.py rpkm
--probes/home/osj118/input/GBM/Gastric/Exome_probe/Exome_probe_capture_library_coordinate.txt
--input /scratch/Gastric_cell_bam/AGS_2.fastq.gz_Illumina_exome_Exome.RGadded.marked.realigned.fixed.recal.bam
--output /home/osj118/output/AGS_rpkm.txt
cd /home/osj118/pyscripts
```

CoNIFER did not work and show error message that

> ImportError: No module named argparse

I already used `sys.append.path` function but it failed to solve my problem.

Strangely, when I ran batch job, CoNIFER worked correctly without any error message.

As batch job violates the rule, I want to use qsub to work in Linux server.

Please give me any solution for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like a pythonpath problem. The pythonpath determines where python can find the required modules. If you installed CoNIFER in a directory together with the packages it uses, then Python will find the packages only if they are on the pythonpath.

You can specify the pythonpath as follows:

export PYTHONPATH=/directory where CoNIFER is installed

Comment: By the way, do you mean that I add 'export PYTHONPATH=/directory' at my qsub script?

Comment: Though your solution was triable solution, unfortunately, it didn't work. I guess that local computer environment and server environment are somewhat different. Perhaps, during assigning permissions administrator missed something important.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, it did not solve the error issue.

However, when I added following code in CoNIFER script manually, it worked.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(where your library located)
```

I have no idea what is wrong.

However, it should be a temporary and quick solution for the similar casess.

Comment: What you are effectively doing by appending the library location to the sys.path is modifying the pythonpath in the application itself.